# Hiding file extensions using web.config file but exclude POST requests

Tags: ajax, url, asp-classic, web-config, file-extension

So i'm trying to hide file extensions in my urls using web.config file, here is my code:

```
    <!-- Remove file extension .asp -->
    <rule name="RemoveASP" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)\.asp" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="AddASP" enabled="true">
                <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.asp" />
           </rule>    
    </rule>
```

However this is causing issues for my contact form when trying to use ajax, it just fails and no data is submitted:

```
var url = "tutors.asp?YS="+YS+"&ORG="+ORG+"&BOTH="+BOTH+"&COM="+COM+"&page=International-Contact";
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                      url: url,
                      cache: false,
                      type: "POST",
                      data: { fname: fname, lname: lname, role: role, forg: forg, location: location, phone: phone, addinfo: addinfo, email: email }
                          })
                      .fail(function(){
                      error = "Oops! There's been a fatal error and the email hasn't sent! Please refresh the page and try again.";
                      $('#error').html(error);
                      return false;
                      })
                      .done(function(){
                      $('#form_container').html("<h3>Thank you!</h3><p>Your email has been sent successfully.</p>");
                      });
              });
```

The ajax code submits to tutors.asp but the rule makes it so i redirect to a url without the asp extension. So how can I exclude redirecting POST requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition for the server variable `REQUEST_METHOD` to your rewrite rule. Here is your rule limited to `GET` requests:

```
<rule name="RemoveASP" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\.asp" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```